# Can't connect to RDS database with PyMySQL

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pymysql

I'm trying to connect to an RDS database in AWS but i get the following traceback:

```
  File "/Users/andreschaves/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 613, in connect
    sock = socket.create_connection(
  File "/Users/andreschaves/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/andreschaves/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Server.py", line 133, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "Server.py", line 31, in main
    cur, connection = start_connection(host, user, psswd, db_name)
  File "Server.py", line 48, in start_connection
    connection = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, password=psswd)
  File "/Users/andreschaves/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/andreschaves/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 664, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '**********' (timed out)")
```

When i created the database i check that i had public access.
This is the code i'm using for the connection:

```
    connection = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, password=psswd, database=db_name)
```

Comment: What did you check exactly? Security groups, public ip?

Comment: I checked the security groups and the connectivity when i was creating the database, the public access is set to: yes, but please, how are the SG suppose to be?

Comment: What is the current security group settings?

Comment: @MarkB Inbound rules: Type: CUSTOM TCP, SSH and MySQL/Aurora, the three of them are with Protocol: TCP and Source: 0.0.0.0

Comment: Is your rds in a public subnet?